# I am getting MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 in mongodb

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple node , typescript api with mongodb. I am using docker to pack the app into a container.

Here is my index.ts :

```
import express from 'express';
import app from './app';


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

here is app.ts :

```
import express from 'express';
import { urlShortenerRouter } from './routes/urlShortener'; 
import connectDB from "./db";

const app = express();

// middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();

// routes
// handle URL Shortening
app.use('/shorten', urlShortenerRouter); // Handle URL shortening

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, URL Shortener!' );
});


export default app;
```

here is dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Node.js LTS image
FROM node:lts

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/index

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build TypeScript code
# RUN npm run build

# Expose port 3000 for the Node.js application
EXPOSE 3000

# Environment variables for MongoDB connection
# ENV MONGODB_URI=mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/mydatabase

# Start the Node.js application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

here is docker.compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data:
```

What is working ?
Docker compse up starts the application as expected.
Mongodb starts properly , so does the server. I am getting back Server is running on port 3000 on the console.

However getting the following error:

```
app-1    | Server running on port 3000
app-1    | Error connecting to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
app-1    |     at _handleConnectionErrors (/usr/src/index/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:875:11)
app-1    |     at NativeConnection.openUri (/usr/src/index/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:826:11) {
app-1    |   reason: TopologyDescription {
app-1    |     type: 'Unknown',
app-1    |     servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
app-1    |     stale: false,
app-1    |     compatible: true,
app-1    |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
app-1    |     localThresholdMS: 15,
app-1    |     setName: null,
app-1    |     maxElectionId: null,
app-1    |     maxSetVersion: null,
app-1    |     commonWireVersion: 0,
app-1    |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
app-1    |   },
app-1    |   code: undefined
app-1    | }
```

I have tried other solutions on the app , such as replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 , but no success.I have tried restarting the container as well but no success
Kindly provide suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your MongoDB connection URI in your Node.js application or environment variables to:

```js
const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/mydatabase';
```

And in your `docker-compose.yml`, make sure the environment variable is correctly set as follows:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/mydatabase
```

This ensures your application connects to the MongoDB service within Docker using the service name `mongo` which you specified in your `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the connection string for MongoDB in your Node.js app or the associated environment variables is updated to:

```
const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/mydatabase';
```

Also, verify that the docker-compose.yml file has the environment variable accurately set like this:

```
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/mydatabase
```

This adjustment guarantees that your app connects to the MongoDB service within the Docker network using the service alias mongo, as defined in your docker-compose.yml.